# Enable JSR356 with jetty-runner

Tags: java, maven, websocket, jetty, jetty-9

I developed a Java server application (spring+hibernate) that use websockets. When I run the app with jetty-maven-plugin all works fine, but if I try to run my application with jetty-runner, then seems that JSR356 are not enabled.

To load my app I run: java -jar c:\jetty.jar --port 8083 --path gateway gateway

Is supposed JSR356 included into jetty-runner? In the opposite case how I can enable it?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, JSR-356 is not included in the jetty-runner.

Your choices:

- Use jetty-distribution
- Manage the classpath yourself, including the relevant JSR-356 jars (apis + impls)
- Make your own embedded-jetty launcher

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what Joakim mentioned, you can use the jetty websockets implementation instead of the JSR-356 one with jetty-runner if JSR-356 support isn't a hard requirement.

I just went through this exercise to get a cometd application running on Heroku so I can confirm that it works.